# how to set the pointer on specific event using powerbuilder button click event

Tags: powerbuilder

I am trying to change the pointer shape at click event of button.
what actually I am trying to do in my script is as:

```
pointer p1
p1= SetPointer(AppStarting!)
Messagebox("Value",integer(p1))
```

but no change occurs at click event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code `Messagebox("Value",integer(p1))` will always show 0 as the value of p1 since this is not how you determine the value of an enumerated datatype.  Take a look at the `GetEnumItemValue` method in the help file.

The pointer gets reset at the start of each method so even though you set it in one event, if you trigger another event it will be changed back to the default value.